# How to delete the text between nodes in xml file using VBscript

Tags: xml, vbscript

I want to delete the text between beacon `<InstalledPlugins>` and  `</InstalledPlugins>` in following xml file.
please help me with this.

```
                       <OceanApplicationShell>
                        <ApplicationShell>
                       <InstalledPlugins>
                        <Plugin>

                    <Author>TechAdvantage</Author>
                    <AppVersion>2012.1</AppVersion>                 
                    <StartMode>Startup</StartMode>
                    <StartupAction>None</StartupAction>
                    <CodeBase>C:\Program Files\Petrel_2012.3\Extensions
                    <InstallerId>{52956779-2949-42AD-A218-B6BD210F8A2F}

                         </Plugin>
                        </InstalledPlugins>
                        </ApplicationShell>
                        </OceanApplicationShell>
```

The output should look like this:

```
         <OceanApplicationShell>
                    <ApplicationShell>
                       <InstalledPlugins>

                       </InstalledPlugins>
                    </ApplicationShell>
         </OceanApplicationShell>
```

I want to do this task conditional. i.e. if `"<Author>"` is "TechAdvantage" only then it should delete text between beacon `“<InstalledPlugins>” & “</InstalledPlugins>”` otherwise it should keep as it is.
This is what i have tried.

```
Set objXMLDoc = Wscript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

 Dim objxmldoc

    objXMLDoc.async = False



    Set objShell=wscript.CreateObject ("wscript.Shell")

    Set fso = wscript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    XMLFile = "path of xmlfile"
    objXMLDoc.load(XMLFile) 
    Set colNodes = objXMLDoc.selectNodes ("/OceanApplicationShell/ApplicationShell/InstalledPlugins/Plugin/Author")
    For Each objXMLDoc in colNodes
       Author = objXMLDoc.getAttribute("Author")& "  " & objXMLDoc.text
    if (objXMLDoc.text = "TechAdvantage") Then
    Set nodes = objXMLDoc.selectNodes("OceanApplicationShell/ApplicationShell/InstalledPlugins")
    For Each node In nodes
     node.parentnode.removeChild(node) 
    Next
    End If
    Next
objXMLDoc.Save (XMLFile)
    Set objShell= Nothing
```

Comment: where is your code?? have you tried something?? plz let us know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an XPath expression that selects only the node(s) you want to delete:

```vbs
author = "TechAdvantage"
xpath  = "//InstalledPlugins/Plugin/Author[text()='" & author & "']/.."

For Each n In objXMLDoc.SelectNodes(xpath)
  n.parentNode.removeChild n
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your ans. But its not working. 
my script is working without condition. but after making it conditional, its giving an error : Error: Object required: ''
on XMLDoc.Save (XMLFile) line.

Comment: @user3176206 Your variable is named `objXMLDoc`, not `XMLDoc`. Use the [`Option Explicit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) statement for detecting problems like this early on.

Comment: I have tried that also. But of no use. its giving same error. Object required: ''
Without condition, same object works fine. But not with condition.

Comment: @user3176206 With the code you posted, `XMLDoc.Save` couldn't possibly work and will *always* raise an `Object required` error. Please update your question with the code you're currently using and the exact error (error number, message and line number) it raises.

Comment: I have updated qus. with my current code. Its giving an error as follows:

---------------------------
Windows Script Host
---------------------------
Line: 25
Char: 1
Error: Object required: ''
Code: 800A01A8
Source:  Microsoft VBScript runtime error

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: @user3176206 Ah, now I see. You're using `objXMLDoc` not only for your XML tree, but also as the loop variable for the outer loop (`For Each objXMLDoc In colNodes`). Don't re-use variables like that. Also, why didn't you use the XPath expression I suggested? That would eliminate the need for an outer loop entirely.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working fine now. Thanks for your valuable response.